# How can we determine the request environment (sandbox / production) in a WSO2 custom handler?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to determine if a request is for a sandbox or production environment in a WSO2 custom handler? How can I get that information?

```
public class CustomHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {
        //GET Environment info...
```

Assume it is an unauthenticated request and it doesn't contain an access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment is always decided based on the access token. If the API is open it's by default sent to the production environment. See [1].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/6.x/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/security/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.java#L197

Comment: This is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53686757/is-it-possible-to-validate-a-jwt-token-created-from-an-external-oauth2-server-in. I have a custom authorization handler that validates an external JWT token. If the cert is for sandbox I want to validate it with a certificate, if it is for prod, with a different one. Then I want the request to go to the configured backend (sandbox/prod)...

Comment: In that case your JWT should tell to which environment it is issued for.

Comment: And what about the processing of the request. I mean, how can I make wso2 process the request in sandbox if as you said, it'll go to production by default?

Comment: Within your JWT validator, you can set `AM_KEY_TYPE` synapse property to `SANDBOX` like this. `synCtx.setProperty(APIConstants.API_KEY_TYPE, "SANDBOX");`